# Editor assignment pending after "review competed"

Tags: publications, journals, journal-workflow

I submitted journal in the field of psychometrics about one year ago.  Three weeks ago, the status was changed to "review completed".  However, today it is changed into "editor assignment pending".  I am not sure what this means. Can you help?

Comment: It's usually best to try not to infer much from the status of a paper listed in an electronic editorial system.  These tools are intended more for the editorial staff than the author, and are often used inconsistently or inaccurately.  If you feel your paper is taking an inordinate amount of time to review, then contact the handling editor; otherwise, just ignore and be patient.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Actually, for all the editiorial systems I have been dealing with, the information is correct as far as I can tell and if they did not want authors to read this information, they would not give it to them. Moreover this information can prevent useless communication with the editors: For example, there is no point in asking the editor why the reviews are taking so long in the situation described in the question. In another example, I would complain if my paper is still not under review after one month, but it’s fine if it is under review at that time.

Answer (score 4):

It's not certain what it means without knowing the particulars of the journal's internal handling, but a likely meaning is that the paper has been handed off from the associate editor who has been handling the reviewing to a senior editor to finalize the decision.  In many journals, an associate editor provides a recommendation for the decision, but a senior editor actually makes the decision; if there are multiple senior editors, then a brief gap before one of them takes up the paper would create the observed behavior.

Bottom line: you are likely to see a decision shortly.

Comment: your answer make sense if article is in initial stage. I am facing similar problem. I submitted an article to springer. The article took 5 months and I got decision with minor revision. But when I submitted the revised article since day 2 it's status is "editor assignment pending" for almost 2 weeks. What does it mean? 
The article will be handled by new editor?
Or the editor is making final decision based on our revised manuscript? Bearing in mind the decision was minor revision.

Comment: @MBK It's unusual to have such a delay, but could be any of those.  More likely than anything else, it means "the person supposed to handle this is badly distracted or on vacation right now."  Since it took 5 months for the first round, you're dealing with a process that's not overly concerned with speed. If it goes for a full month, then I would recommend emailing the editors, but not before then.